# C# design help- to handle instances of providers

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am looking for a design technique to achieve the following.

- two different data sources to read data
- I need to be able to dynamically add or remove more data sources

What I have done so far is, I have created the following :

```
IDataProvider 
- StartReadData()
- EndReadData()
- List<DataObjs> (contains data)

   XmlDataProvider : IDataProvider
   CsvDataProvider : IDataProvider

IDataProviderManager
- List<IDataProvider> (has a collection of dataprovider)

  DataProviderManager : IDataProvideManager
```

Now, I am looking for a better technique by which I can instantiate IDataProviders and manage it in a configurable way (**add or remove more IDataProviders classes without doing any changes to code or recompiling**).

Any nice design techniques or links to similar code are welcome.

Much Thanks.

Comment: Nothing that fancy: dataProviders.Add(new XmlDataProvider("data.xml"));

Comment: Take a look at the [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern.

Comment: I dont want to hard code any types to add to teh providers. I would rather use a config file to get the provider type name and instantiate it using reflection. But, I am looking for  some code samples that could do this or some known design ideas.

Comment: @Steven - I did take a look but I need to be able to dynamically add and remove data providers without recompiling code. Using dependency injection containers like Unity could do this but I am looking for a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the factory-pattern to abstract away the instantiation of the providers as a first step.

In that factory you can go either way with the implementation: config, reflection etc.

But my guess is that you will end up using an IoC-container in the long run as they are doing exactly what you want (and better)

Most containers can scan assemblies and import them transparent to your application without the need for recompiling.

I would suggest to invest a little time in getting to know DI instead of losing time on inventing your own solution. (which will be something to learn from too btw)

Using the factory allows you to change the implementation without breaking your application when you find the final solution that suits you.

Comment: yes, I think this would be the best approach short term and long term. Hence marking it as right answer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you keep your providers in a separate assembly, you can define them in a config file and instantiate them at runtime:

```
 <DataProviders>
 <provider name="XmlDataProvider" 
      type="Separate.Assembly.Providers.XmlDataProvider, Separate.Assembly"/>
<provider name="CsvDataProvider" 
      type="Separate.Assembly.Providers.CsvDataProvider, Separate.Assembly"/>
</DataProviders>
```

Your code then has to read and parse the config, then load the types dynamically.

Comment: I don't think providers have to be in different assembly necessarily. They can be in the same assembly. Only the classes have to be different.

Comment: They have to be in a different assembly **from the loading assembly** as OP wants to be able to change them without recompiling.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I quickly had to craft this as an approach. Upvoted this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to recompile everytime, then the solution could be mix of your own solution and the one provided by @Stuart Dunkeld.

1. Define some interface like `IDataProvider`.
2. Write some config section handler (implement [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx) ) and configure all data providers (classes implementing `IDataprovider`) in the application configuration.
3. Add some "manager" class that loads the configured data provider for a specific type. You may use something like [IUnityContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.iunitycontainer%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) to know the dependency and resolve it.